# Converting 2-byte hex data from G-sensor to float

Tags: java, netty

I need to read acceleration on all 3 axes (X, Y, Z) from an accelerometer as float values in m/s<sup>2</sup>. Quoting from the device documentation:

> Data for each axis uses **two bytes**. The range is set to **±16g**. Data from G-sensor (14-bit precision) is expressed in **two's complement notation**. For example:

- `0x00 0x4D` for X-axis means `0.36 m/s²`
- `0xFF 0xEC` for Y-axis means `-0.10 m/s²`
- `0xFD 0xFB` for Z-axis means `-7.39 m/s²`

I'm trying to do the conversions for the examples above using [`Netty ByteBuf`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html). Unfortunately [`readFloat()`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#readFloat--) can't be used because it will try to read 4 bytes instead of 2.

Please guide me on how to obtain the right float values from 2-byte hex.

Comment: 0x4d = 77 decimal. How to you get from 77 to .36?

Comment: @K.Nicholas that's literally their question, how do they go from the hex to the values shown =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Math:

- since the range is ±16G: `G = input / 0x8000 * 16 = input / 2048.0`
  (`0x8000` because `0x7FFF` is max positive number)
  (double needed here since `input` is an integer type)
- and since `1G = 9.81m/s²`; `a = 9.81 * input / 2048.0`
  (or `a = input * 9.81 / 2048.0`)

The method for this (if needed) could be:

```
double convert(short input) { 
    return input * 9.81 / 2048.0;
}
```

Test:

```
IntStream
.of(0x00_4D, 0xFF_EC, 0xFD_FB)
.mapToObj(i -> "%04X -> %5.2f m/s²".formatted((short)i, convert((short)i)
 )
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

resulting in

> ```
> 004D ->  0.37 m/s²
> FFEC -> -0.10 m/s²
> FDFB -> -2.48 m/s²
> ```

Are you sure that `-7.39 m/s²` is correct for the 3rd value?

I do not know Netty `ByteBuf`, but it also has a [`readShort()`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#readShort--) that should read two bytes as short that can be given to above method, or just converted directly - the method is not really needed (mind correct order of bytes, see also [`readshortLE()`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#readShortLE--))

Comment: All examples are from the device documentation, so I don't know if `-7.39 m/s²` is the correct value for the 3rd example. It could be a mistake in the documentation. It bothers me a bit that only the second result in your solution is exactly like in the examples (`FFEC -> -0.10`). The first is `0.37` instead of `0.36` and the last is completely different as you noticed.

Comment: If the documentation's FDFB was a typo and the intended value was F9FB, then that would convert to -7.38. The small discrepancies are nothing to worry about. The value of g is approximate and not constant: it is different in different parts of the Earth. Also, the accuracy of accelerometers is not that great.